# Edição de perguntas com frases gramaticalmente mal construídas

Tags: discussion

**[Pergunta original](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/499/m%C3%BAltiplos-adjetivos):**

Em Português, os adjetivos objectivos são colocado depois os substantivos, como:

> o autocarro vermelho

mas o que é o caso para múltiplos adjetivos? Por exemplo, em Inglês, nós escrevemos:

> the old, red car

ou

> the old, red, rusty car

que é o frase correto em português? Será que todos os adjetivos vem depois do substantivo?

[Por favor não hesite comentar no meu português, obrigado.]

---

A pergunta tem algumas frases mal construídas.
Ao editá-la, em vez de substituir o que está mal, devemos destacá-lo e apresentar a correção no fim, ou não devemos sequer editá-la?

**Edição proposta:**

Em Português, os adjetivos objectivos são colocado depois os substantivos, como:

> o autocarro vermelho

mas [o que é o caso para]<sup>1</sup> múltiplos adjetivos? Por exemplo, em Inglês, nós escrevemos:

> the old, red car

ou

> the old, red, rusty car

[que é o frase correto]<sup>2</sup> em português? Será que todos os adjetivos vem depois do substantivo?

[Por favor não hesite comentar no meu português, obrigado.]

<sub>1 - mas como é no caso de</sub>
<sub>2 - como é a frase correta</sub>

---

Tendo em conta que quem fez a pergunta não é fluente em português, não será útil para ele poder ver, ao mesmo tempo, o correto e o incorreto?
É algo que devemos fazer ou não?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that the main goal of a question is to obtain the solution to what the question is specifically asking for, we should focus our answers on just that: **keep orthographic and grammatical corrections as edits to the question**, and avoid placing those in the answer. Future visitors will thank you for this, as they will find clean questions and answers to what they were looking for without being mixed with secondary issues.

Some people might think it sounds uninviting, but not at all. Those who edit (or suggest edits to) the question can still comment on those issues if really necessary. Otherwise, adding an edit with a summary of the changes made and leaving a small remark of *"I have corrected your Portuguese, please check the question's edit history"* will suffice. If they did not understand the correction, they may do one of three things:

1. Research and (maybe) ask a new question.
2. In small cases, reply to that correction with a comment in the question.
3. Send the discussion to chat, requesting the corrector to participate.

---

[Portuguese version will be written by request.]

Comment: Great answer. By the way, one can also "comment" in the course of editing, since there is a description/"edit summary" field.

Comment: Indeed, good point.

Answer (score 7):

Acho que a qualidade de uma pergunta (ou resposta) é muito mais importante do que a visibilidade de correções gramaticas.

Ele pode sempre dar uma olhada na historia das edições e você pode enfatizar isso em comentários.

Comment: Parece que estamos de acordo.

Comment: Estamos sim! Eu não notei a sua resposta até eu coloquei a minha :)